# Labels on Rects in Vega Stacked Bar Chart

Tags: vega

In the old vega-label documentation there is reference to a [labeled stacked bar chart example](https://github.com/vega/vega-label/blob/master/README.md#in-stacked-bar-chart---stacked-bar-chart-example). The example spec doesn’t work in the online Vega editor, throwing an error that a.map is not a function.

I am trying to do almost exactly what is referenced in the above example: create a vertically-stacked bar chart where each segment is labeled with its value. I have seen a few examples of this in Vega-Lite with layers, but how can it be achieved in Vega?

I’ve attempted to recreate the above spec using a group containing the rect mark and the text mark, but I’m not getting it right. I also see how to display the value as a tooltip on hover, but I’d like it displayed in the rectangle of each segment of the bar itself.

Ideally I would end up with a chart like this:
[image: vertically-stacked bar chart with labels for each type of land use]

Here’s the spec I’ve been working with:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic stacked bar chart example.",
  "width": 294,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "categories",
      "values": [
        {"y": 5, "c": 0, "name": "other"},
        {"y": 7, "c": 1, "name": "corn"},
        {"y": 22, "c": 2, "name": "pasture/hay"},
        {"y": 31, "c": 3, "name": "developed"},
        {"y": 35, "c": 4, "name": "forest"}
      ],
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "stack",
          "field": "y"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true, "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": "category",
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],

  "axes": [
  ],

  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "categoriesBars",
      "type": "group",
      "from": {"data": "categories"},
      "zindex": 1,
      "marks": [
        {
          "type": "rect",
          "from": {"data": "categories"},
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "x": {"value": 0},
              "width": {"value": 294},
              "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
              "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
              "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}
            },
            "update": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 1}
            },
            "hover": {
              "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "text",
          "encode": {
            "enter": {
              "y": {"field": {"parent": "y"}},
              "x": {"value": 130},
              "fill": [
                {"test": "contrast('white', datum.fill) > contrast('black', datum.fill)", "value": "white"},
                {"value": "black"}
              ],
              "align": {"value": "center"},
              "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
              "text": {"field": {"parent": "name"}}
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide a sample spec. Please also mark your old questions as solved.

Comment: Are you just trying to add labels to the following example? https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/stacked-bar-chart/

Comment: Yes, something similar. The example I referenced shows this:
https://github.com/vega/vega-label/raw/master/pics/examples/label_rect_stack.png

I also just added an image to my original post for clarification of what I’m intending to create.

Comment: I also added a sample Vega spec to my original post. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v5.json",
  "description": "A basic stacked bar chart example.",
  "width": 294,
  "height": 200,
  "padding": 5,
  "autosize": {"type": "fit-x", "contains": "padding"},
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "categories",
      "values": [
        {"y": 5, "c": 0, "name": "other"},
        {"y": 7, "c": 1, "name": "corn"},
        {"y": 22, "c": 2, "name": "pasture/hay"},
        {"y": 31, "c": 3, "name": "developed"},
        {"y": 35, "c": 4, "name": "forest"}
      ],
      "transform": [{"type": "stack", "field": "y"}]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "y",
      "type": "linear",
      "range": "height",
      "nice": true,
      "zero": true,
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "y1"}
    },
    {
      "name": "color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": {"scheme": "pastel2"},
      "domain": {"data": "categories", "field": "c"}
    }
  ],
  "axes": [],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "i",
      "type": "rect",
      "from": {"data": "categories"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"value": 0},
          "width": {"value": 294},
          "y": {"scale": "y", "field": "y0"},
          "y2": {"scale": "y", "field": "y1"},
          "fill": {"scale": "color", "field": "c"}
        },
        "update": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 1}},
        "hover": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "from": {"data": "i"},
      "encode": {
        "update": {
          "y": {"field": "y"},
          "dy": {"signal": "(datum.y2 - datum.y)/2"},
          "x": {"signal": "width/2"},
          "fill": [
            {
              "test": "contrast('white', datum.fill) > contrast('black', datum.fill)",
              "value": "white"
            },
            {"value": "black"}
          ],
          "align": {"value": "center"},
          "baseline": {"value": "middle"},
          "text": {"field": "datum.name"}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes! This is super-helpful and exactly what I’m looking for. Many thanks!